# Dynamic variable T-SQL (using stored procedure)

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have got a table-valued function with parameters :

```
SampleProcedure(@date,@par1,@par2,@par3)
```

Date variable is an INT , for example :

```
@date int = 20170102
```

What I would like to do is to iterate through next days until EOF or specific , predefined date , so the @date variable should change once the previous iteration is done. Other parameters are not changing.

What approach should I take? I was wondering if I should use cursors , but I don't really understand them at the moment - I'd be thankful if anyone explains me them at this example (iteration through dates as ints).

EDIT :

More specific case :

I have got GetDailyUsageReal and GetDailyUsageForecast stored procedures.

- GetDailyUsageReal(@date,@par1,@par2)
- GetDailyUsageForecast(@date,@par1,@par2)

My input :

```
DECLARE @date int = 20170102,
@par1 INT = 4000,
@par2 INT = 1,

;WITH CTE as (SELECT Hour, SUM(CAST(UsReal AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / 1000000 as Real, Day
 FROM GetDailyUsageReal(@date,@par1,@par2)
Group BY Hour,Day),

CTE2 as (SELECT Hour, SUM(CAST(UsForecast AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / 1000000 as Forecast, Day
 FROM GetDailyUsageForecast(@date,@par1,@par2)
Group BY Hour,Day)

SELECT cte.Hour, Real, cte2.Forecast , cte.Day
FROM CTE
JOIN CTE2 on cte.hour=cte2.hour AND cte.day=cte2.day
ORDER BY cte.hour
```

The output is :

```
+------+------+----------+----------+--+
| Hour | Real | Forecast |   Day    |  |
+------+------+----------+----------+--+
|    1 |   10 |       12 | 20170102 |  |
|    5 |   24 |       23 | 20170102 |  |
|    7 |   24 |       22 | 20170102 |  |
|    8 |   27 |       27 | 20170102 |  |
|    9 |   26 |       21 | 20170102 |  |
|   10 |   21 |       21 | 20170102 |  |
|   11 |   11 |       12 | 20170102 |  |
|   12 |   25 |       24 | 20170102 |  |
|   13 |   17 |       18 | 20170102 |  |
|   14 |   18 |       19 | 20170102 |  |
|   15 |   26 |       25 | 20170102 |  |
|   16 |   22 |       21 | 20170102 |  |
|   17 |   23 |       23 | 20170102 |  |
|   18 |   24 |       23 | 20170102 |  |
|   19 |   19 |       18 | 20170102 |  |
|   20 |   10 |       11 | 20170102 |  |
|   21 |   11 |       13 | 20170102 |  |
|   22 |   18 |       16 | 20170102 |  |
|   23 |   19 |       17 | 20170102 |  |
|   24 |   11 |       13 | 20170102 |  |
+------+------+----------+----------+--+
```

What I want to get is basically output for the next days, let's say until 2019 (there's some data even for 2019 in my DB).

So what I need is the iteration of date. I have no access to change @date data type to DATE.

@EDIT2 :

My expected output :

```
+------+------+----------+----------+--+
| Hour | Real | Forecast |   Day    |  |
+------+------+----------+----------+--+
|    1 |   10 |       12 | 20170102 |  |
|    5 |   24 |       23 | 20170102 |  |
|    7 |   24 |       22 | 20170102 |  |
|    8 |   27 |       27 | 20170102 |  |
|    9 |   26 |       21 | 20170102 |  |
|   10 |   21 |       21 | 20170102 |  |
|   11 |   11 |       12 | 20170102 |  |
|   12 |   25 |       24 | 20170102 |  |
|   13 |   17 |       18 | 20170102 |  |
|   14 |   18 |       19 | 20170102 |  |
|   15 |   26 |       25 | 20170102 |  |
|   16 |   22 |       21 | 20170102 |  |
|   17 |   23 |       23 | 20170102 |  |
|   18 |   24 |       23 | 20170102 |  |
|   19 |   19 |       18 | 20170102 |  |
|   20 |   10 |       11 | 20170102 |  |
|   21 |   11 |       13 | 20170102 |  |
|   22 |   18 |       16 | 20170102 |  |
|   23 |   19 |       17 | 20170102 |  |
|   24 |   11 |       13 | 20170102 |  |
|    1 |   15 |       14 | 20170103 |  |
|    5 |   18 |       11 | 20170103 |  |
|    7 |   26 |       44 | 20170103 |  |
|    8 |   21 |       33 | 20170103 |  |
|    9 |   22 |       12 | 20170103 |  |
|   10 |   21 |       21 | 20170103 |  |
|   11 |   11 |       12 | 20170103 |  |
|   12 |   15 |       12 | 20170103 |  |
|   13 |   17 |       18 | 20170103 |  |
|   14 |   18 |       19 | 20170103 |  |
|   15 |   26 |       25 | 20170103 |  |
|   16 |   22 |       21 | 20170103 |  |
|   17 |   23 |       23 | 20170103 |  |
|   18 |   24 |       23 | 20170103 |  |
|   19 |   19 |       18 | 20170103 |  |
|   20 |   10 |       11 | 20170103 |  |
|   21 |   11 |       13 | 20170103 |  |
|   22 |   18 |       16 | 20170103 |  |
|   23 |   19 |       17 | 20170103 |  |
|   24 |   11 |       13 | 20170103 |  |
+------+------+----------+----------+--+
```

I just want to have values from dates between selected range ,or range from selected day till end of file - last row in DB basing on day (so the last day could be for example 20210131). I want to have them in one result table, as shown above.

@EDIT after changes :

Output :

```
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Hour |   Real    | Forecast  | Workdate |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 20   | 11.831587 | 15.140129 | 20170101 |
| 21   | 11.659364 | 15.003950 | 20170101 |
| 22   | 11.111199 | 14.736179 | 20170101 |
| 23   | 11.075579 | 14.812968 | 20170101 |
| NULL | NULL      | NULL      | NULL     |
| 1    | 9.930323  | 12.856905 | 20170102 |
| 2    | 9.826946  | 12.741908 | 20170102 |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: you issue is not clear enough

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and the expected output for each input?

Comment: I suggest you use a datetime parameter (not int). An integer like 20170102 is a very inconvenient way to store a date value.

Comment: I am not an owner of DB, therefore I cannot change the way of storing values.

Input example in the EDIT.

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. There's no reason to iterate or use cursors. If you want to perform an operation on a date range write a query that includes those dates. Cursors are used in *very* rare cases as they are the most complex, slowest way to perform a job. Post the actual calculation you want to perform, the query you already have

Comment: @Pejczi you can definitely change the way the *variable* is stored. Plus, you don't need it, just like you don't need cursors to work with date ranges. What are you trying to do? What is the actual calculation you want to perform? You havent' explained that, only how you think it can be done

Comment: Calculating a sum over a date range is easy, just use a `Where date between @startDate and @endDate`. Calculating a difference between the current and *previous* date can be done using an analytic function like LAG or LAST_VALUE, eg ` somefield - LAST_VALUE(ORDER by date desc)`

Comment: Or you can use `LAG(somefield,7) OVER(Order by date desc)` to compare a value with the same vaule last week.

Comment: How to change the way the variable is stored, when parsing it into function? Shouldn't the procedure output the error that data types are not matching? In this case, probably the conversion is the solution to bypass the error, isn't it?. I have edited my expected output. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pejczi, I have done this logic for you. You need a CTE to build all the dates that you are interested in. Then join the table function with an outer apply - this ensures that a valid date is passed to the function and thus returns the hour and forecast/real column for each date. 
Let me know how it goes:

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE='20170101'
    DECLARE @EndDate DATE='20180601'--current_timestamp


    DECLARE @Dates TABLE(
          Workdate DATE  Primary Key
    )

    ;WITH Dates AS(
          SELECT Workdate=@StartDate
          UNION ALL
          SELECT CurrDate=DateAdd(DAY,1,Workdate) FROM Dates WHERE Workdate<@EndDate
    )


    SELECT *

    FROM 
        Dates D
        OUTER APPLY 
            (
             SELECT Hour, SUM(CAST(UsForecast AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / 1000000 as Real, Day as WorkDate
             FROM GetDailyUsageReal(CONVERT(CHAR(8),D.Workdate,112),@par1,@par2)
             GROUP BY 
             Hour,Day
            )R

        OUTER APPLY 
            (
             SELECT Hour, SUM(CAST(UsForecast AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / 1000000 as Forecast, Day as WorkDate
             FROM GetDailyUsageForecast(CONVERT(CHAR(8),D.Workdate,112),@par1,@par2)
             GROUP BY 
             Hour,Day
            )F
    ORDER BY
    d.Workdate

 option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work :



Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
(the error points line 13, which is ;WITH Dates AS(... ) )

Comment: @Pejczi - I have modified it. the reason is the table function expects integer. See the updated version.

Comment: Works perfectly, I will just add some aggregation and will fulfill my expectations. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Okay, it somehow takes unmatching Forecast values (multiplying rows for hours and date, but I'll find out how to fix it)

Comment: Okay, @Pejczi, it is now clearer what you are doing. You might need to rebuild the CTE dates to include hours, so you can join them based on dates and hours. I will post a new answer to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Maybe you could just give me some hint so that I could find it out at my own? I really appreciate your help. @EDIT -  I see you have added a new answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@openshac suggestion is valid. You should store date as DATE datatype and using StartDate/EndDate it will make it easier to query. See if you can replace:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE ='20170102'
```

with

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE ='20170102'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE ='20180102'
```

Comment: The thing is, I am not an owner of DB. I have no write permissions, I can only use read queries.

Comment: @Pejczi post your query, explain what you want to do. Iteration is how you think the problem can be solved, not the problem itself. 99.999999% of the time It's the worst possible solution.

Comment: @Pejczi, for clarification: GetDailyUsageForecast(@date,@par1,@par2) and  GetDailyUsageForecast(@date,@par1,@par2) are table valued functions. They return tables when you pass the date variable. It is not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This version expands on the CTE dates and adds hour column, so you can join the real/forcasted table functions on the Hour.

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME='20170101'
  DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME='20170201'--current_timestamp


    DECLARE @Dates TABLE(
          Workdate DATE  Primary Key
    )

    ;WITH Dates AS(
          SELECT Workdate=@StartDate,WorkHour=DATEPART(HOUR,@StartDate)+1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT CurrDate=DateAdd(HH,1,Workdate),DATEPART(HOUR,DateAdd(HH,1,Workdate))+1 FROM Dates WHERE Workdate<@EndDate
    )


 SELECT Workdate=CAST(Workdate AS date),WorkHour
     FROM 
        Dates D
    OUTER APPLY 
            (
             SELECT Hour, SUM(CAST(UsForecast AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / 1000000 as Real, Day as WorkDate
             FROM GetDailyUsageReal(CONVERT(CHAR(8),D.Workdate,112),@par1,@par2) R
             WHERE R.Hour=D.WorkHour
             GROUP BY 
             Hour,Day
            )R

        OUTER APPLY 
            (
             SELECT Hour, SUM(CAST(UsForecast AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / 1000000 as Forecast, Day as WorkDate
             FROM GetDailyUsageForecast(CONVERT(CHAR(8),D.Workdate,112),@par1,@par2) F
             WHERE F.Hour=D.WorkHour
             GROUP BY 
             Hour,Day
            )F

    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Msg 9810, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
The datepart hour is not supported by date function datepart for data type date. I have changed DATE to DateTime and it works. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. Just one question : wonder why it does not get hour "24" - instead it outputs full NULL row?

Comment: I have added a new EDIT to main post showing results at the end of the day and beginning - there's not 24 hour, it shows null.

Comment: I found out what's the reason. For example : let's take a sample date : 2017-01-01 23:00. In my table, it is shown as Workday : 20170102 , Hour : 1 . Therefore it causes NULL values, and not showing "24" hour as normally when using @date as INT. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: @Pejczi, the issue is that the CTE table hour goes from 0-23, So when it link to your GetDailyUsageReal/GetDailyUsageForecast, it cant find that value Hour=0. But you can easily change it by adding 1 to the loop, so it starts at 1. Like this  DATEPART(HOUR,@StartDate)=>DATEPART(HOUR,@StartDate)+1. Let me edit the query to clarify.

Comment: Wow, wouldn't find it out. I was trying to work with parameter inside DateAdd() function , but it didn't get expected results - your solution works perfectly. Thank you a lot for your help, everything seems to be okay at the moment. I need to study T-SQL further, because I didn't know about APPLY function and all datatype workarounds you have used. Again - you're a lifesaver :-)